# How does the following code enter an infinite loop if abs(guess**2 -x) >= epsilon (line 7)?

Tags: python, loops

I don't understand why does this  code enter an infinite loop. I've tried debugging to see the problem but that didn't help much.
The program keeps looping between the while and first if statement.

```
x = 25
epsilon = 0.01
step = 0.1
guess = 0.0

while guess <= x:
    if abs(guess**2 -x) >= epsilon:
        guess += step

if abs(guess**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print('failed')
else:
    print('succeeded: ' + str(guess))
```

Comment: could it be because x hasn't been declared yet?

Comment: You missed the x assignment.  But, guess does not get updated unless the condition is True, causing an infinite loop.  Perhaps you need an `else: break` added to the if statement.

Comment: I just added the x variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `break`

```
x = 25
epsilon = 0.01
step = 0.1
guess = 0.0

while guess <= x:
    if abs(guess**2 -x) >= epsilon:
        guess += step
    else:
        break

if abs(guess**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print('failed')
else:
    print('succeeded: ' + str(guess))
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your guess reaches a value of 5, the conditional stops being met and your guess isn't incremented anymore. After that, your program loops infinitely.